# Collision doesn't work work if i drag too fast

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, flash-cs6

I'm searching for this all day but it gives me the answer-box2d and I'm just a BEGINNER, box2d is advance for me, i don't really understand it. Someone help me, any answer will be appreciated.
    hero.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, touchhero);
    stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, drophero);

```
var dragbound1:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);

function touchhero(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    hero.startTouchDrag(event.touchPointID, false, dragbound1);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gohero);
}
function drophero(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    hero.stopTouchDrag(event.touchPointID);
}

function gohero(event:Event):void{
if(hero.hitTestObject(wall)){
   //popup something
}
}
```

Comment: How are we supposed to help with a question like this? Show some code, show what doesn't work right. We can't divine the problem out of 2-3 sentences.

Comment: Motion speed of object do affect collision systems you can understand it easily. If an object x position is at 30 on one frame and 60 on the next frame (30px motion) that object has never been at any position in between (31, 32, 33, etc) now if you check if that object has been at let's say 45 it will fail cos that object has never been there. Collision system typically prevents that by calculating the next position of the object and precheck the collision.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but.. then what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You should use pixel perfect collision detection. Firstly you still want to check if your MovieClip's bounding box collides with another (the same method you're currently using). This is done to save your game from constantly checking the collision in such detail. If this is the case you can now check for the pixel collision.

Here's a good tutorial on this: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pixel-level-collision-detection--active-10862